# How to force caching in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, caching, header

How do I force caching of pages, scripts, images(resources) including the results of dynamicly generated content (php,asp,etc etc), I do not have control of the website in question and I understand that if I cache a dynamic page it becomes static,, thats fine for me,,

However... I do not want to cache everything.. the pages loads default.asp,,,as well as a tone of .js scripts,,, in turn which make calls to a API returning some XML,,

I want to cache the default.asp and all .js but not the xml files.

im using chrome and chrome is aggressively caches what it can but all the stuff from this site has a max-age=0 header.

so from chrome how can I override headers for individual resources?